# heroku push tutorials confusing

Tags: mysql, database, windows, heroku, push

When it comes to pushing databases,the problem starts for the amateurs.

i have my local mysql installed in windows 7,and referring to the heroku tutorial

http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/taps they say that you can specify heroku db:push

mysql://root:mypass@localhost/mydb in the command line My question is Do i have to include

anything in my source code related with postgres? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

When on Heroku, unless you have specified otherwise, you'll be running on Postgres.  It you're using an ORM to access your database, then chances are you'll be OK.

If not, then there are literally hundreds of differences between PG SQL and MySQL SQL so something will probably need tweaking depending on how complex your queries are.

Also, depending on the platform you're using you might need to include some dependencies for Postgres such as the `pg` gem for Ruby.

Something worth noting is that if you're using Rails, you can just do `heroku db:push` and Heroku does the rest for you ;)